# How do I fix the pyaudio wheel download error?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am having an error downloading `pyaudio`, but there is a way to fix that by downloading a wheel, but I am also having an error downloading that too. How do I fix this error?

Comment: pls provide the errors you are getting while downloading Python Audio and wheel both.

Comment: [ask] please review this and see if you can reformat the question.

Answer (score 0):

Get your appropriate `.whl` file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/) under `pyaudio`. You can find the appropriate `.whl` file by typing python in your `cmd` or `terminal`. You would get something like this:

```
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

**Image description:**

[image]

Note the python version and if python is 64 or 32 bit. Then get the `.whl` file appropriate for that version and machine. For me it would be this `.whl` file:

```
PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Next, go to the place where it was downloaded. For example, `C:\Users\user\Downloads>` then install `.whl` file using `pip`. For example in my case:

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: thanks for replying but i tried the same procedure before posting a Question on stack overflow, but it says "the .whl file is not compatible with python version"

Comment: what version of the wheel are you using.

Comment: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

Comment: @MaxAnthony Is your bit really 32 bit? Look at my image description in my above-edited post.

Comment: @MaxAnthony if your python version is 3.8 and your bit is probably 64-bit try this wheel: `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` from: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio