# ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. when installing with pipwin

Tags: python, pyaudio, python-wheel

I've been trying to install PyAudio on vs code using `pipwin install PyAudio` but I'm getting a

> `ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

error.

```
PS C:\Users\Alyoshka\OneDrive\Documents\Project> pipwin install PyAudio
Package `pyaudio` found in cache
Downloading package . . .
https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/x6hvwk7i/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
File C:\Users\Alyoshka\pipwin\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl already exists
ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pipwin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pipwin\command.py", line 103, in main
    cache.install(package)
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\pipwin\pipwin.py", line 301, in install
    subprocess.check_call([executable, "-m", "pip", "install", wheel_file])
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\python3.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'C:\\Users\\Alyoshka\\pipwin\\PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl']'hl']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
PS C:\Users\Alyoshka\OneDrive\Documents\Project>
```

So how do I change the wheel to be the correct one? And how do I know which wheel to use, it says that it's using python 3.9 on 64bits?

Comment: What python version and bit are you using? You can find out by typing `python` in your terminal.

Comment: it says `Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 23 2021, 09:13:41)  [GCC 10.3.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: Why don't you just install the wheel from: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio with the same name and then install it normally using pip? Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70542794/how-do-i-fix-the-pyaudio-wheel-download-error/70552951#70552951

Comment: I tried that but it gave me the same `ERROR: PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` error. I tried doing it in the vs code terminal and in cmd in the `downloads` path but both gave me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip debug` to see if `cp39` is a compatible tag for your python.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).